# Make bash differentiate between Ctrl-<letter> and Ctrl-Shift-<letter>

Tags: linux, bash

I was wondering whether there was any way of making bash send different codes for key combinations that include the shift key? for instance, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shows me that) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> are interpreted the same (^N). Or is there a terminal that can make the difference? Or can bash me modified so that it does?

Comment: It's dependent on your terminal emulator. My emulator (Terminal.app) does not send `^C` when I press `Ctrl+Shift+C`.

Comment: But I don't have a mac...

Comment: The point is that it is dependent on your terminal emulator.

Comment: Well yes, so could you recommend me one that would make the difference?

Comment: I'm not on Linux, unfortunately. Sorry :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A terminal doesn't interact directly with your keyboard; it interacts with a stream of bytes that it receives, which are usually (but not necessarily) generated by your keyboard. For the printable ASCII values, there is an obvious correspondence between the value and a key (or combination) on your keyboard. ASCII 97 is <kbd>a</kbd>, ASCII 65 is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, and so on.

However, there are the 32 non-printing *control* characters from ASCII 0 to ASCII 31, called which because they were intended to *control* a terminal. In order to enter them, the <kbd>Control</kbd> was added to allow you, in combination with the other keys, to generate these codes. A simple scheme was used. Pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>-*x* will generate the control code corresponding to subtracting 64 from *x*. Since <kbd>@</kbd> generates ASCII 64, <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> generates ASCII 0. The same mapping holds true for <kbd>A</kbd> through <kbd>_</kbd> (consult your favorite ASCII reference to see the rest of the correspondences).

However, whether or not you need a shift key to generate ASCII 64 through ASCII 95 depends on your keyboard. On my US keyboard layout, only <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> can be typed without a shift key. (Remember, it's the *uppercase*-letter ASCII range we're using here, not the lowercase.) So to simplify, I suspect it was decided that <kbd>Shift</kbd> would be ignored in determining which keycode is sent with <kbd>Control</kbd>-*x*. (Note that if for some reason your keyboard had two of the characters between 64 and 95 generated by a key/Shift-key pair, your terminal would need to define an alternate mapping for the associated control character.)

All this is simply(?) to explain why <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>-*x* and <kbd>Control</kbd>-*x* are typically the same. Obviously, your modern operating system can distinguish all kinds of keyboard combinations. But out of the myriad possibilities, only 256 of them can send unique values to a terminal; the rest must necessarily duplicate one or more of the others. To be useful, they need to be configured to send some multiple-byte sequence to the terminal, typically beginning with ASCII 27 (ESC). When terminals receive that byte, they pause for a moment to see if any other bytes are coming after. Keys like function keys, arrow keys, etc. have fairly standard sequences they send, which the terminal interprets in various ways. Other keys (like <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> in your example) have no agreed-upon meaning, and so your terminal emulator must assign one. Most emulators should allow you to do this, but how they do so is, obviously, program-specific.

Comment: Thank you. I am using a US layout as well. Is it possible to modify what the emulator assigns to different key bindings? Let's say bash.

Comment: `bash` is not your emulator; the emulator is `xterm` and the like.

Comment: OK. But please, tell me, as far as you know is there way at all for me  to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There's are two great write-ups on keyboard shortcut customization in bash here:

[Bash: call script with customized keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119991/bash-call-script-with-customized-keyboard-shortcuts)

[In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command)

Comment: Unfortunately not really related. The problem is that Ctrl+A and Ctrl+Shift+A both emit the same key code.

Comment: My bad.  What system are you working on?  On my Fedora box, default key mappings for CTL + Shift mostly belong to the system, not individual applications.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04. Basically I need this for emacs. Ctrl+e goes to the end of the line. I would like Ctrl+shift+e to mark until the end of the line (in terminal mode - emacs -nw, in GUI mode it works.

Answer (score 0):

iTerm2 allows you to map key combinations like <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (which should represent `C-<`) to an escape sequence. Emacs translates certain escape sequences to the expected key sequence by default. Therefore, by remapping the desired key combination in iTerm to the appropriate escape sequence, you can get the behavior you want. See [this response](https://superuser.com/a/1502869/1113420) for specifics.